# Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, avd-manager

I am trying to run an android emulator on Linux mint.

When I try to run the avd , on the emulator, I get the following error.

```
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

When I navigate to android_sdk/system-images/android-21/default/armeabi-v7a

There exists a kernel file called kernel-qemu

I guess there is some sort of compatibility issue between the emulator and my avd?

Is there a way to resolve this?

Below is the script I use to install my android tools, and create the avd...

```
# use sdkmanager to install all the tools 
SDKGET=~/android_sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager 
$SDKGET "build-tools;29.0.2" 
$SDKGET "emulator" 
$SDKGET "platform-tools" 
$SDKGET "platforms;android-21" 
$SDKGET "platforms;android-24" 
$SDKGET "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a" # lollipop 5.0
$SDKGET "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a" # Nougat 7.0
$SDKGET "system-images;android-26;default;x86" # Orea 8.0

# use avdmanager to create the virtual devices
AVDMAKE=~/android_sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager 
$AVDMAKE create avd -n Nexus4_5.0_api21 -k "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a" --device "Nexus 4" # 1280X768
$AVDMAKE create avd -n Nexus5_7.0_api24 -k "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a" --device "Nexus 5" # 1920 x 1080
$AVDMAKE create avd -n Nexus6P_8.0_api26 -k "system-images;android-26;default;x86" --device "Nexus 6P" # 2560 x 1440
```

Comment: i have the same problem did you find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was just to use the android-24 and android-26 system images. They worked when the android-21 did not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an older version of the Android Build Tools, if possible. Something like `"build-tools;28.0.3"` or `"build-tools;27.0.3"`

Someone here -- https://github.com/mingchen/docker-android-build-box/issues/38 -- said that the problem could be caused by the files in the `Android-SDK/emulator/` folder not working correctly, when the newer versions of the Build Tools are installed.

I don't know if there's a way to downgrade the files in `Android-SDK/emulator/`, but you can copy the folder from an old installation and replace it in your new installation. And you should check for a file named `emulator64-arm`, and check the `source.properties` to see what build tools version it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because Android emulator was updated in a recent version to expect the 'kernel-ranchu' file instead of the 'kernel-qemu' file. Therefore, system images for older versions of Android that only include 'kernel-qemu' may not work properly with the new emulator.

Therefore I fix it with these steps:

1. Visit Android Studio menu "**Tools**" -> "**SDK Manager**" -> "**Appearance & Behavior**" -> "**System Settings**" -> "**Android SDK**" ->  "**SDK Platforms**" tab -> Tick bottom right "**Show Package Details**"
2. Scroll to "**Android 5.0 (Lollipop)**" and untick to uninstall existing both "**Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image**" and "**Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image**" (to clear old incomplete which only have kernel-qemu but missing kernel-ranchu). Click "**OK**" to start uninstall.
3. Android Studio menu "**Tools**" -> "**Device Manager**" -> "**Create device**" -> "**Nexus 5**"(got Play Store) -> "**x86 Images**" tab -> choose "**Lollipop 21 x86_64 Android 5.0 (Google APIs)**" -> "**Next**" -> "**Finish**" (which re-install and both kernel-qemu and kernel-ranchu files appear in the folder of error log above, in my case is `Found systemPath D:\Android\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-21\google_apis\x86_64\`)
4. Launch the new created device, the error gone.